# How to meassure the length of common edges between polygons?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, shapefile, polygon, measurements, borders

I have a shapefile that contains several polygons which in fact represent the limits of several counties. My task is to find each length of each shared border. So in other words I want to know how many km of border share the A county with the B county and so on. Of course I am looking for a tool to do this automatically. Measuring them manually would take ages. I envision some sort of matrix, but not sure how to do that in ArcGIS.

I use ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 (ArcEditor) .

10x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000p000000) tool by setting output_type to "Line". The result will be edges of all input (polygon) layer. Just calculate the length of the output(line) and that is it.